# "this" seems to have value from old iteration in handlebars "each" helper (using in mandrill template)

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, mandrill

I have handlebars based email template for mandrill and am trying to render JSON data from a list of lists where each list can have up to 3 items. For each inner list handlebars iterates over, it is supposed to check if there is anything at index 0,1,2 and if so do something with them, like this:

```
{{#each thing}}
    {{#if this.thing.[0]}}
        Do something here
    {{/if}}
    {{#if this.thing.[1]}}
        Do something here
    {{/if}}
    {{#if this.thing.[2]}}
        Do something here
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I have noticed that when the list being iterated over only has 2 items, handlebars will take the 3rd item from the last list that had 3 items, so I guess this.[2] isn't block scoped?

For instance if I use:

```
thing = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e"]
]
```

I get:

```
Something with "a"
Something with "b"
Something with "c"
Something with "d"
Something with "e"
Something with "c"
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with mandrills implementation of handlebars of handlebars itself, as I'm new to both.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Currently it seems like Mandrill changes the context in the #each block a bit funny. This is not from Handlebars, but rather - Mandril's implementation of it (and I hope they fix it). If there are 2 objects being iterated over, and the first one has a property, but not the second (in your case -> this.thing.[2]) - when the second one comes into scope, the property does not get 'cleared'. What you could do is assign it to 'false' explicitly -

```
thing = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e", false]
];
```

Might be easier if you use objects instead of arrays, this.[2] looks less readable than this.c ( I am assuming you meant this.[2] instead of this.thing[2] ). E.g. using

```
 thing = [
    { a : true, b : true, c : true },
    { d : true, e : true, c : false}
]
```

with the same template should work just fine. {{@key}} gives you access to the keys.

Comment: Thank you for this. This exact issue has been driving myself and my product owner up the wall. I am now explicitly setting the value to `null`, which is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you should iterate 2 times with #each and not use #if

Here is an example

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each thing}}    
    {{#each item}}
        {{value}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/y1nmx738/

Comment: I wish I could do this but I'm not doing the same thing at each index